# Sql for room availability

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have following table structure

**rooms** table

```
||| room_id ||| name |||
|||    1    ||| best |||
|||    2    ||| best |||
|||    3    ||| best |||
|||    4    ||| best |||
```

**bookings** table

```
||| room_id ||| date_start |||   date_end     |||
|||    1    ||| 2015-01-10 |||  2015-01-15    |||
|||    2    ||| 2015-01-10 |||  2015-01-18    |||
|||    3    ||| 2015-01-05 |||  2015-01-10    |||
|||    4    ||| 2015-01-02 |||  2015-01-05    |||
```

what i want is lets say if a user search for **date_start = 2015-01-10** and **date_end = 2015-01-14**

I want to show the available rooms for those days.

This is what i have tried so far

```
SELECT r.*
FROM rooms r
WHERE r.room_id NOT IN (
    SELECT b.room_id FROM bookings b
    WHERE (b.date_start   <= '$data[datestart]' AND b.date_end >= '$data[dateend]'))
```

thank you!

Comment: Can you share what you've tried?

Comment: Does MySQL support OVERLAPS?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at the possibilities:

```
x/y = your query's "find available for these days"
a/b = various records' start/end in your db
```

Here's every possible variant:

```
   a    b
---+----+---
xy |    |     // no overlap
x  | y  |     // partial overlap
x  |    | y   // complete overlap
   | xy |     // complete overlap
   | x  | y   // partial overlap
   |    | xy  // no overlap
```

Once you crunch the logic down, you end up with

```
(y < a) || (x > b)   // no overlap at all
```

Comment: this is an interesting way of thinking, is this a known method (if yes what is it called?), or is it just your way of analyzing OP's question? Thanks

Comment: it would be `(y <= a) || (x >= b)` if you allow a afternoon check-in on same day as a morning check-out

Comment: @joe: it's basically just boolean algebra. write out an expression for each line of the overlap chart, put all the expressions together, then reduce them.

Comment: What about the situation where x is less than a, and y is greater than b?

Comment: @McAdam331: whoops, right...forgot to add that one to the chart (fixed...), but it'd still be excluded

Comment: Maybe you should mention that it based on the characteristic x < y ;-)

Comment: Hmm I suppose you're right. I should have approached this with Boolean logic, you have fewer conditions than I do.

Answer (score 1):

If you are considering a date range such as 01/10 and 01/14, there are three situations where a room is unavailable:

- Someone has a start date between 01/10 and 01/14
- Someone has an end date between 01/10 and 01/14
- Someone has a start date before 01/10 and an end date after 01/14.

So, for the first two you can use the `BETWEEN` operator to see if dates fall in the range, and for the others use greater than or less than.

What I would suggest, is write a query to get unavailable rooms:

```
SELECT r.*
FROM room r
JOIN bookings b ON b.room_id = r.room_id
WHERE b.date_start BETWEEN '2015-01-10' AND '2015-01-14'
  OR b.date_end BETWEEN '2015-01-10' AND '2015-01-14'
  OR (b.date_start < '2015-01-10' AND b.date_end > '2015-01-14');
```

And then you can use `NOT IN` to select from the rooms_table any rooms that aren't in this forbidden list:

```
SELECT r.*
FROM room r
WHERE r.room_id NOT IN(
  SELECT r.room_id
  FROM room r
  JOIN bookings b ON b.room_id = r.room_id
  WHERE b.date_start BETWEEN '2015-01-10' AND '2015-01-14'
    OR b.date_end BETWEEN '2015-01-10' AND '2015-01-14'
    OR (b.date_start < '2015-01-10' AND b.date_end > '2015-01-14'));
```

If you want to avoid the subquery, you can just negate each of your conditions to get *available* rooms:

```
SELECT r.*
FROM room r
JOIN bookings b ON b.room_id = r.room_id
WHERE b.date_start NOT BETWEEN '2015-01-10' AND '2015-01-14'
  AND b.date_end NOT BETWEEN '2015-01-10' AND '2015-01-14'
  AND (b.date_start >= '2015-01-10' OR b.date_end <= '2015-01-14');
```

Here is an [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/99bd6/8) with all three examples.

Comment: Hi Thank you!..But i have a small problem,all my booking information is in another separate table like ( customer name,email )..How can select all from that table too?

Comment: You can just include another join on a column that relates the booking table and the customer table.

Comment: it relates using booking_id, please tell me where can i include it?..thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT rooms.room_id, rooms.name FROM rooms
INNER JOIN bookings
ON rooms.room_id =bookings.room_id 
WHERE bookings.date_start >= DATE('2015-01-10') AND bookings.date_end <= DATE('2015-01-14');
```

Comment: What if someone booked a room from 01-11 to 01-12? That room would be unavailable but returned by your query.

Comment: true, that's like checking on bookings between two dates, not available rooms.

Comment: Hey sorry i didn't consider it.I was  thinking on the specifics provided in question.
Thanks