# SQL query to search for room availability

Tags: sql, sql-server

The follow tables I have are:

```
 CUSTOMERS (CustomerID, firstname, surname etc)
 ROOMS (RoomID, RoomType, Description)
 BOOKING (BookingID, CustomerID, Arrival Date, Departure Date, number of people, total cost)
 ROOMS_BOOKED (BookingID, RoomID)
```

The user enters two dates arrival and departure. Then checks for room availability. There is a room booked at the moment which I have inserted into the database myself. So the BOOKING table now includes BookingID = 1, CustomerID = 1, Arrival Date = 24/03/2015, Departure Date = 26/03/2015, number of people = 1, total cost = 40.00. Then in the ROOMS_BOOKED table I Have BookingID = 1 and RoomID = 2 which is a standard room.

I am using this sql code -

```
   SELECT RoomType FROM ROOMS WHERE RoomID NOT IN (SELECT RoomID FROM ROOMS_BOOKED)
```

This query is returning rooms that have not been booked, but is not what Im looking for. For example the user selects the same dates that are booked in the database. I therefore want to be able to display all room types on the next page and display an x or something for the particular room type that is booked on those selected dates, something similar to www.galgorm.com.

I need help with this, everytime I post a question about this I never get an answer or some form of help. I have got so far with this hotel system with the design, I now want to be able to finish it off.

Please help me, im sure sometimes you have been in the same situation needing help.

Comment: Sounds like you want some sort of `LEFT JOIN` so that it will return results, but you can conditionally also tell whether they have been booked or not.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Sql for room availability](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27987511/sql-for-room-availability)

Comment: Don't you need to add dates to your query?

Comment: If im querying my database for room availability, will I just stick with the rooms table and the booking table? or do I need to query the Rooms_booked table?

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Comment: im using sql server and visual studio 2012

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You have the following cases

```
The user's selected period:
--------[---------]-------
Booking no1 
[-----]-------------------
Booking no2
--------------------[----]
Booking no3
-----[----]---------------
Booking no4
-----------[---]----------
Booking no5
------[-------]-----------
Booking no6
--------------[--------]--
Booking no7
-----[----------------]---
```

You will have to find which periods cross over.
Obviously cases 1 and 2 are free.
Cases 3,5,6 are easy to catch as you can search if either the start date of the booking or the end date of the booking is within the user's selection.
Cases 4 and 7 you would need to find if either of the user's selection dates would be between the bookings.

So the following finds free rooms:

```
DECLARE @ArrivalDate AS DATETIME
DECLARE @DepartureDate AS DATETIME

SELECT RoomType 
FROM ROOMS 
WHERE RoomID NOT IN 
(
    SELECT RoomID 
    FROM   BOOKING B
           JOIN ROOMS_BOOKED RB
               ON B.BookingID = RB.BookingID
    WHERE  (ArrivalDate <= @ArrivalDate AND DepartureDate >= @ArrivalDate) -- cases 3,5,7
           OR (ArrivalDate < @DepartureDate AND DepartureDate >= @DepartureDate ) --cases 6,6
           OR (@ArrivalDate <= ArrivalDate AND @DepartureDate >= ArrivalDate) --case 4
)
```

Comment: Thank you for your reponse :) I hope this solves me question. I now have to ouput the results into a gridview this is going to get complicated lol :/

Comment: @stevendornan It depends on how do you define the datasource. In the codebehind for instance you could say something like `GridView1.DataSource = results` where `results` is whatever has been returned from running the query. I am more into MVC than Forms, and i would also use EF for this.

Comment: I have been developing this system in visual studio 2012, using .Net and VB, as I have been taught this at university. Is it possible that when the user selects the two dates and clicks the check availability button a gridview  appears on another page displaying the available rooms based on ur query? If that makes sense. I really appreciate your time and effort :)!

Comment: Well, the short answer is that it really can no matter the technology. But the proper answer with samples etc would be big enough to fit in a comment. To try and put you in the right direction (hopefully) one way of doing this is have a page with a grid that would accept lets say a querystring (?arrival=...&departure=...). On the Page_Load you would get results from the db adding the querystring params and populate the gridview with the results. On the page where selection is being made, you would have two fields for the dates and a submit button which would redirect to the grid page.

Comment: Another approach would be to utilize some ajax to not have to move to another page. To be honest this really depends on what technologies you are familiar with, though it wouldn't be bad for you to try get your hands on something new.

Comment: Booking systems arent so easy lol Im doing this as interest, to improve my programming skills for final year. Looking back on your query,            "SELECT RoomID 
    FROM   BOOKING B" I dont understand this as theres no room id in the booking table? or is there something you have missed ? I enjoyed reading your comments, it has helped me. Thanks again.

Comment: I am `JOIN`ing that table with the `ROOMS_BOOKED` table. So the results will have that column. Glad to be of any help.

Comment: Now I understand :D your a genius!

Comment: By the way, if you want a word of advise. Have a look at newer technologies, as you say you are fresh, so lets do it fresh. Learning COBOL won't help much nowadays. In my oppinion you should have a look at how `Entity Framework`, `ASP.NET MVC`, and it since i hate the pages being loading etc, tryout learning some javascript framework (`JQuey` and `Angular` are fantastic choises). You do need to stand out when you start your career. Anyway, this is just my personal point of view. After all there are still sites on WebForms, and hell... there are still companies using COBOL!!!

Comment: Just wanting to know do you have an email address? :) so I can show you my project. and if you have any ideas you can share them, thats only if you have time.

Comment: Yeh your rite :) It does no harm to look at other languages/ frameworks. I am so glad I have got talking to, you have made my day, now I am able to progress. Im trying to learn as much as possible for when I do start a career as a web developer.

Comment: Thanks. Ill be in touch soon.

Answer (score 3):

this query list all rooms and for each room shows if it is available within [Arrival , Departure] dates

```
SELECT 
    RoomType,
    case when NOT EXISTS (SELECT RoomID 
                  FROM ROOMS_BOOKED rb 
                  JOIN BOOKING b on b.BookingID = rb.BookingID
                  WHERE rb.RoomID = r.Id 
                    and ArrivalDate < 'param Departure Date here'
                    and DepartureDate > 'param Arrival Date here')
        then 1 else 0 end IsAvailable
FROM ROOMS r
```

Answer (score 1):

Conflicting booking happens when both the conditions below are satisfied

1. Existing Records **CheckIn Dates** < inComingRequest **CheckOut Date**
2. Existing Records **Checkout Dates** > inComingRequest **CheckIn Date**

> Note: Existing Records **CheckinInDates** compared against InComing
> Request's **CheckoutDate** and viceversa

lets assume incoming req params:

```
 SET @checkInDate := '2022-09-14'; -- incoming req.checkInDate
 SET @checkOutDate := '2022-09-17'; -- incoming req.checkOutDate
```

BOOKING table containing some existing bookings :

[image: ExistingBookings]

Actual Query to get all conflicting bookings:

```
select * from BOOKING B where 
B.checkInDate < @checkOutDate
AND B.checkOutDate > @checkInDate
```

Output (all conflicting bookings):

```
booking_id  checkInDate checkOutDate
       1    2022-09-1   2022-09-30
       2    2022-09-12  2022-09-15
       3    2022-09-15  2022-09-18
       6    2022-09-14  2022-09-17
```

booking_id 4 is excluded as the Customer who has existing booking would have just checked out of the hotel when this customer checks in.

booking_id 5 is excluded as the Customer who has existing booking would check in to the hotel just when this customer checks out.

So booking_id 4 and 5 are not actually conflicting with the incoming req

Answer (score -1):

here is a sample query which i used for checking the rooms which are not available, the query will return the unavailable rooms

```
SELECT roomno FROM tbl_ReservedRooms WHERE ((fromdate BETWEEN @checkindate AND @checkoutdate )
OR (todate BETWEEN @checkindate AND @checkoutdate)) 
AND status = 'Active'
```

Answer (score -1):

SELECT * FROM room rm WHERE rm.Room_id NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT Room_id FROM booking bk WHERE (bk.arrive_date BETWEEN '$from_date' AND '$to_date') OR (bk.departure_date BETWEEN '$from_date' AND '$to_date') OR (bk.arrive_date<'$from_date' AND bk.departure_date>'$to_date'))

Comment: Please explain what the code in your answer does for people that are new to the technology so they can understand and re-user your code :-)