# Sql search date between range of dates

Tags: mysql, sql, date-range

I have two tables in database

1. rooms: contains details of rooms
2. booking: containd booking information about rooms

rooms:

```
+----+----------+---------------+---------+
| id | hotel_id | room_category | room_no |
+----+----------+---------------+---------+
|  1 |        1 | delux         |       1 |
|  2 |        1 | delux         |       2 |
|  3 |        1 | delux         |       3 |
|  4 |        1 | delux         |       4 |
|  5 |        1 | delux         |       5 |
+----+----------+---------------+---------+
```

bookings:

```
+----+------------+----------+---------------+--------------+---------------+---------+----------------+
| id | booking_id | hotel_id | room_category | checkin_date | checkout_date | room_no | booking_status |
+----+------------+----------+---------------+--------------+---------------+---------+----------------+
|  1 |          1 |        1 | delux         | 2016-08-25   | 2016-08-30    |       1 | y              |
|  2 |          2 |        1 | delux         | 2016-08-25   | 2016-08-28    |       2 | y              |
+----+------------+----------+---------------+--------------+---------------+---------+----------------+
```

Now i write an query:

```
select * from rooms
 where
 hotel_id =1 and
      room_category="delux" 
       and id not in(

select room_no
from bookings 
where 
       checkin_date between '2016-08-25' and '2016-08-28'
       or
       checkout_date between '2016-08-25' and '2016-08-28'

       );
```

problem:
1. while searching for availability from 26-27 result contains room no  1and 2 as well

Comment: what exactly is the problem? the inner query will return nothing for 26/27, and you are using `not in`, so all should be returned

Comment: The problem is not clear !

Comment: @Belal his narrative isn't very good but the issue is clear if he searches for the 26th to the 27th instead of the 25ht & 28th as he shows then the checkin_date IS NOT BETWEEN the 26th & 27th and neither is the checkout_date.  He has his BETWEN organized incorrectly and also doesn't account for when checkin_date is < 26th and checkout_date > 27th

Comment: @dhyanandra , please show the primary and foreign keys ?

Comment: @Belal they seem to be pretty obvious hotel_id, room_no is the relationship

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL query to search for room availability](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29213183/sql-query-to-search-for-room-availability)

Comment: It's a clear question - ignoring the gaping flaw of the missing desired result - but I also agree that it's a duplicate. Upvote or close? I'm conflicted, but dnoeth's answer is better than the accepted one over that the suggested duplicate, so I'm just going to leave it alone.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The usual logic to check for overlapping periods is: `begin_1 < end_2 and end_1 >= begin_2` as a hotel room can be booked on the same day when the previous booking ends.

```
select * from rooms
where hotel_id =1 
  and room_category="delux" 
  and id not in
   (
     select room_no
     from bookings  
     where checkin_date  < '2016-08-28'
       and checkout_date >= '2016-08-25'
   );
```