# SQL Free Rooms between Dates and at a specific Time

Tags: sql

I have read a few articles about finding available rooms, however I cannot get my version to work.

Can somebody have a look at my SQL and maybe shed some light on my problem please.

Tables

```
RoomTBL(RoomNo, RoomName)
LessonsTBL(LessonID, RoomID, StaffID, TimeSlot)
DatesTBL(DateID, LessonID, startDate, endDate)
```

I want to find available rooms on a particular TimeSlot, between the StartDate and endDate. (Its a block booking system for a school)

I have tried

```
SELECT RoomNumber 
FROM RoomTBL 
WHERE RoomNumber NOT IN (SELECT RoomNumber 
                   FROM LessonsTBL LT 
                   JOIN DatesTBL DT ON LT.LessonID = DT.LessonID  
                   Where(DT.startDate <= '2016-03-21' AND DT.endDate >= '2016-03-21') 
                   OR (DT.startDate < '2016-04-21' AND DT.endDate >= '2016-04-21') 
                   OR ('2016-03-21' <= DT.startDate AND '2016-04-21' >= DT.startDate)
                   AND LT.TimeSlot = 1)
```

but it doesnt return any rooms (I have 6 rooms not in use at all) I hope I have explained the issue correctly.

No doubt I am missing something, Thanks.

Comment: what is `Timeslot` here?

Comment: I have 24 different half hour timeSlots, I just number them 1 to 24. So in the working system I would pass the selected timeslot through (I have just added in 1 to test)

I have also tested without the time slot and still no results.

Comment: You need to provide sample data and expected output. Your design seems dubious bc your dates are determined by lesson, not room. And you seem to have 2 ways you're trying to identify ""rooms not in use".

Comment: Finally, if your query returns zero rows - then your subquery is returning ***every single room***. This doesn't correlate with your assertion that you"have 6 rooms not in use at all". How do you determine that a room is use at a particular time?

Comment: Craig Young, Thanks for your reply. I have taken this from this example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29213183/sql-query-to-search-for-room-availability

Only difference is I have 24 timeSlot on each day, so I need to see if it is free at that TIMESLOT Between the Start and End date.

Comment: in the LessonTBL I have a timeslot field (which holds a number between 1 and 24) I have 6 rooms in my room table but I have only created 1 lesson and 1 corresponding Date entry. (Meaning 5 rooms should be returned)

Comment: I have managed to return rooms available on those dates, however I cannot get it to recognize the timeslot value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I have understood what you are trying to do, but you are trying to select RoomNumber (which isn't a field in any of the tables) from LessonsTBL. I have made a lot of assumptions in this answer, so please clarify if I guessed incorrectly.

You seem to be looking for a room which is not booked for the first timeslot on any days between '2016-03-21' AND '2016-04-21'

```
SELECT RoomID
FROM LessonsTBL
WHERE RoomID NOT IN
 (SELECT RoomID 
  FROM LessonsTBL LT JOIN DatesTBL ON LT.LessonID = DT.LessonID
  WHERE LT.TimeSlot = 1 AND (DT.startDate BETWEEN '2016-03-21' AND '2016-04-21') OR (DT.endDate BETWEEN '2016-03-21' AND '2016-04-21')
```

Unless you need the RoomName, you don't need the RoomTBL.

Comment: Thank you I managed to get it working, however its not what I need- I need it to only block book the same Day each week between the dates not every single day.

Comment: WhatEva. Is there anyway I can modify this code to only check the same day each week (between the start and endDates) instead of checking EVERY day???