# Postgres Check availabilty overlapping dates

Tags: postgresql

I need a way to find out when items are available for use. The items are reserved for a period of time, the amount of time varies per client's need. 
I need a way to find out what is available within a time frame.

I looked at overlaps and >, < scenarios but I am not able to figure this out. Example of my tables are below.

Widget table

```
| id | color  | length | purchase_date | in_date  |
|----|--------|--------|---------------|----------|
| 1  | red    | 1.5    | 07/02/15      | 08/22/19 |
| 2  | red    | 2      | 07/02/15      | 08/22/19 |
| 3  | blue   | 1.5    | 08/15/14      | 08/22/19 |
| 4  | blue   | 2      | 08/15/14      | 08/20/19 |
| 5  | green  | 1.5    | 06/22/15      | 08/20/19 |
| 6  | green  | 2      | 08/15/14      | 08/20/19 |
| 7  | yellow | 1.5    | 07/02/15      | 08/17/19 |
| 8  | yellow | 2      | 05/04/17      | 08/17/19 |
| 9  | purple | 1.5    | 05/04/17      | 08/30/19 |
| 10 | purple | 2      | 07/02/15      | 08/30/19 |
```

Loan table

```
| loan_id | widget_id | client_id | out_date | in_date  |
|---------|-----------|-----------|----------|----------|
| 1       | 1         | 101       | 08/12/19 | 08/22/19 |
| 2       | 3         | 101       | 08/12/19 | 08/22/19 |
| 3       | 5         | 101       | 08/12/19 | 08/22/19 |
| 4       | 2         | 102       | 08/15/19 | 08/20/19 |
| 5       | 4         | 102       | 08/15/19 | 08/20/19 |
| 6       | 10        | 103       | 08/16/19 | 08/20/19 |
| 7       | 8         | 104       | 08/15/19 | 08/17/19 |
| 8       | 9         | 104       | 08/15/19 | 08/17/19 |
| 9       | 1         | 105       | 08/23/19 | 08/30/19 |
| 10      | 2         | 105       | 08/23/19 | 08/30/19 |
| 11      | 7         | 106       | 08/23/19 | 08/28/19 |
| 12      | 3         | 106       | 08/23/19 | 08/28/19 |
| 13      | 5         | 107       | 08/18/19 | 08/22/19 |
| 14      | 8         | 107       | 08/18/19 | 08/22/19 |
| 15      | 1         | 101       | 09/02/19 | 09/09/19 |
| 16      | 7         | 101       | 09/02/19 | 09/09/19 |
| 17      | 6         | 101       | 09/02/19 | 09/09/19 |
| 18      | 8         | 108       | 08/26/19 | 09/06/19 |
| 19      | 10        | 108       | 08/26/19 | 09/06/19 |
| 20      | 4         | 108       | 08/26/19 | 09/06/19 |
| 21      | 9         | 109       | 08/22/19 | 08/27/19 |
| 22      | 2         | 109       | 08/22/19 | 08/27/19 |
| 23      | 3         | 110       | 09/04/09 | 09/11/19 |
| 24      | 5         | 110       | 09/04/19 | 09/11/19 |
```

The item cannot be checked out on the same day it was checked in.
So, for example, I need to check what is available in between 8/21 & 8/26 (if any) and what is available between 9/8 & 9/14.
We are working with hundreds of these and want to start reserving weeks or months in advance, currently it is a week or two.
All I need out of the widget table for the time being is the ID which will link to the loan table widget_id.

Comment: Please reduce the examples to the minimum. Is it really necessary to see 24 records per table to understand your problem? Furthermore, please add the expected output!

Comment: You have to define an exclusion constraint on the table, using a timestamp-range data type. `ALTER TABLE loan
  ADD CONSTRAINT widget_time_idx 
    EXCLUDE USING gist (widget_id WITH =, (tstzrange(in_date, out_date)) WITH &&);`

Comment: Yes, it shows the variability of the data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

select  id, color, length
from widgets
    where id not in
        (Select widget_id from loan 
    where(start_date <= @start_date and end_date >= @end_date)
    or  (start_date < @end_date and end_date >= @end_date)
    or  (@start_date <= start_date and @end_date >= start_date)
    )
This is the page I referenced:

[SQL query to search for room availability](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29213183/sql-query-to-search-for-room-availability)